# How to use WM2003 binary (dll) on Windows Mobile 6.1 (WM6.1) device ? (PE-loader can't accept old binaries)

Tags: dll, windows-mobile, portable-executable, windows-mobile-6.1

***Hi!***

I have an old plugin (as binary, dll), used by my application. It was build for **WM2003**. And now it crashes the app, if loaded on **Windows Mobile 6.1** (**WM5** works fine, **WM6** too).

The source code is not available and it's no more supported by developer. So I can't rebuild it for **WM6.1**.

Is it possible to patch or convert the binary to allow it to work on **WM6.1** ? If so, how can I do this ?

***Thank you.***

---

**Edit:** I've found, that the [problem is in PE loader](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=2722275&postcount=37), which acts not the same on WM6.1 (comparing with WM6 and earlier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is rare, but some information can be found.

The common solution is to rebuild a binary in VS2008 ([TCPMP new VS2008 builds for WM6.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=380387)), but this will not help, if you don't have the source code.

I've found the problem explanation and another solution in cegcc mailing list ([arm-wince-cegcc on Windows Mobile 6.1](http://www.mail-archive.com/cegcc-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01504.html)). In [Windows Mobile 6.1 Memory Management](http://bolingconsulting.com/blog/?p=4) scheme was changes.

> This slot arrangement remained pretty constant from **Windows Mobile 2003** to **Windows Mobile 6.0**.  However, with the release of **Windows Mobile 6.1**, things were changed to reduce the **DLL** pressure and to help out in the **Device Manager** process space.
>
> In **Windows Mobile 6.1**, the stacks for the device manager are no longer allocated in the processes’ slot. Instead, the operating system uses **slot 59**, at the top of the **Large Memory Area**, for the device manager thread stacks. [...](http://bolingconsulting.com/blog/?p=4)

And the workaround for this issue is to declare the DLL in registry (to tell the OS not to load it in high memory).

I don't like this workaround, so I try to find some binary patcher. And found it :)

It's not really a patcher, it's **UPX** - [the Ultimate **Packer** for eXecutables](http://upx.sourceforge.net/). But it solves the problem perfectly. The DLL, packed with **UPX** don't crashes the application and runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

Does this plug-in use MFC or ATL?  Earlier versions of WinMo had a different ATL/MFC version baked in, so MFC or ATL apps written in Studio will not work unless you deploy the newer ATL/MFC libraries along with the app, just as the old apps will not work on new devices unless you deploy the old MFC/ATL libraries.

Comment: Thanks for answer. No, it's pure C module. Looks like the problrm is in PE-loader.

Comment: What tool are you using to generate the binaries?  I've never seen this problem, and I've run stuff compiled back with the old 3.0 tools user 6.x.

Comment: It's mot me. The DLL developer is not accessible anymore. Looks like it was MSVS 2003 arm compiler.